# Tag CZ synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I noticed that [cz](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cz) is synonym of [china-southern-airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/china-southern-airlines). But I have expected that it would be a synonym of [czech-republic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/czech-republic) so I think that the tag synonym should be changed or deleted

Answer (score 2):

I'm in favor of simply deleting the synonym.

CZ is the IATA airline designator for China Southern Airlines, and would appear in flight numbers (e.g. CZ18), as well as the ISO 3166-1 2-letter designation for the Czech Republic. In this case, I agree that most current users of this will associate the letters *cz* with the latter, especially since we are not in the habit of using the IATA codes (although sites like Airliners.net and FlyerTalk.com use them almost exclusively). This will not always be the case, however, so we cannot make a rule out of it.

For example, BA is the common abbreviation and the IATA designator for British Airways, but also the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code for Bosnia & Herzegovina. Despite that some participants on the site believe labels applied to countries should override other usages, I think it unlikely that anyone on an English-language travel website will first think of the country first when coming across "BA." In fact, I think BA as the NYSE ticker symbol for Boeing might even come second.

There are a huge number of often overlapping codes and abbreviations that a traveler contends with, and it may not be possible to develop a policy as to which one a 2-4 character code refers to  without upsetting some sensibility or another:

- common names and abbreviations for places and organizations
- IATA airport code
- IATA and GDS city codes
- ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 and alpha-3 country codes
- ISO 4217 currency code
- ISO 639 language code
- timezone abbreviation
- IATA railway station designator
- Local railway station designator
- IATA airline designator
- IATA aircraft type designator
- IATA region code
- IATA meal code
- ICAO airline code
- ICAO location identifier
- airline fare basis code
- airline flight status code